# Java: install jps and jcmd packages only on linux

Tags: java, linux

I have a minimal version of Java installed in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-xx-openjdk-xx/`. I want to add `jps` and `jcmd` libs, but I don't want to install the whole `openjdk-xx-jdk-headless` to keep a minimal install.

How can I install only these packages?

Comment: bellsoft-java21-lite-amd64 has both